# EntityFramework Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

1. New Project - Class Library
2. Guget Packages - Install-Package EntityFramework, Install-Package MySql.Data, Install-Package MySql.Data.Entities, Install-Package MySql.Web
3. `<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, 
       MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
       EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
   </entityFramework>`
4. Add New Item - ADO.NET Entity Data Model
5. Empty EF Designer - Finish
6. Right Click on the model properties and then DDL Generation Template to SSDLToMySQL.tt
7. Sample entity added
8. Build Solution
9. Right Click- Generate Database from Model
10. Select Data Connection and hit next.

Then the window close and nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

[Adding References Using NuGet Versus an Extension SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj161096(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Install the EF6 NuGet package**

You need to upgrade to the new Entity Framework 6 runtime.

Right-click on your project and select Manage NuGet Packages...

Under the Online tab select EntityFramework and click Install

**Note:** If a previous version of the EntityFramework NuGet package was installed this will upgrade it to EF6.

Checklist:

1. EF5 is built into the core of .NET 4.5, whereas EF6 has been shifted
   out, and is open source.

   - This means that you must add the new EF6 assemblies to all of the    relevant projects in the solution, in particular the entry project.
   - This means that you must remove assembly System.Entity from all    projects, as this refers to EF5.
2. EF5 has a single .dll "EntityFramework.dll", whereas EF6 has two
   .dlls:

   - EntityFramework
   - EntityFramework.SqlServer
3. EF6 requires changes to app.config. The best way to make these
   changes is to right click on the Solution, select "Manage NuGet
   Packages for Solution", search for "EntityFramework" and install
   v6.1.0 of Entity Framework into all of the relevant projects, in
   particular the entry project. Make sure you uninstall any NuGet
   packages for EF5 Framework from all projects. This will
   automatically update your app.config files so they are correct.
4. Examine all app.config files for references to EF5, and remove them.
5. The namespaces have changed:

   - Remove C# lines "using System.Data.EntityClient;", which is an EF5    reference.
   - Add C# line"using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;" which is the    correct for EF6.

This checklist is a Community Wiki,

Comment: @GertArnold That question is edited before one hour.before editing,i think this ans is fair to that question.